# Function on a nested array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my Function which turns timestamps to seconds,

```
   const convertor = (x) => {
      const result = x.split(':');
      const final =
        parseInt(result[0] * 60) +
        parseInt(result[1] * 60) +
        parseInt(result[2]) -
        1.2;
      return final;
    };
```

input = 00:01:02.330
result: 62.330

How can I implement it on a nested array like this?

array = **[**  **[** 00:01:02.330],[00:01:04.550],[01:11:02.330]  **]**, **[**  [00:01:02.330],[00:01:02.330]  **]** , **[**  [00:01:02.330],[00:01:02.330],[00:01:02.330] **]**  **]**

I want to preserve its nested structure so the result should be:

**[**  **[** 22.3],[28.5],[903.50]  **]**, **[**  [1252.3],[62.2]  **]** , **[**  [654.25],[965.25],[1254.32] **]**  **]**

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include code blocks using backticks (`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a wrapper that accepts a function and an array, and maps over the array-- if the item is an array, it recurses; otherwise, it passes the item into the passed function-- this allows you to process nested arrays of any arbitrary depth and retain the desired structure:

```js
const convertor = (x) => {
  const result = x.split(':');
  const final =
    parseInt(result[0] * 60) +
    parseInt(result[1] * 60) +
    parseInt(result[2]) -
    1.2;
  return final;
};

const recursiveNestedMapper = (fn, arr) => {
  const output = arr.map((item) => {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      return recursiveNestedMapper(fn, item);
    } else {
      return fn(item);
    }
  });

  return output;
}

const inputArray = [
  [
    ['00:01:02.330'],
    ['00:01:04.550'],
    ['01:11:02.330']
  ],
  [
    ['00:01:02.330'],
    ['00:01:02.330']
  ],
  [
    ['00:01:02.330'],
    ['00:01:02.330'],
    ['00:01:02.330']
  ]
];

const outArray = recursiveNestedMapper(convertor, inputArray);

console.log(outArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're keeping the timestamps in an array when it's the only element, but you can get the desired output by chaining [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const convertor = (x) => {
  const result = x[0].split(':');
  const final =
    parseInt(result[0] * 60) +
    parseInt(result[1] * 60) +
    parseInt(result[2]) -
    1.2;
  return final;
};

const array = [
  [ [ '00:01:02.330' ], [ '00:01:04.550' ], [ '01:11:02.330' ] ], 
  [ [ '00:01:02.330' ], [ '00:01:02.330' ] ], 
  [ [ '00:01:02.330' ], [ '00:01:02.330' ], [ '00:01:02.330' ] ] 
];

const output = array.map(a => a.map(b => convertor(b)));
console.log(output);
```

```json
[
  [
    60.8,
    62.8,
    720.8
  ],
  [
    60.8,
    60.8
  ],
  [
    60.8,
    60.8,
    60.8
  ]
]
```